# ссылка на dropdown

Tags: bootstrap, dropdown

как нa dropdown-e поставить ссылку где

```css
body{
    padding:10px;
}

.show-on-hover:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        
        
        <div class="btn-group show-on-hover">
          <a href="ssylka.ru" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

       
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <a href="ssylka.ru" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Action </span>
 </a> - не рабртает

Comment: Перед ссылками на внешний ресурс нужны два слеша "//ssylka.ru". Везде, не только в бутстрапе. http : // www.ssylka.ru - вот здесь два слеша играют ту же роль, говорят что это внешний ресурс.

Comment: еще на мобильном версии не открывается dropdown